# What is diffrence implementing xtify using GCM and xtify using XMPP in android?

Tags: android, xtify

if we are implementing the push notification in android then What is diffrence implementing xtify using GCM and xtify using XMPP in android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xtify XMPP:

**pros:**

- Works with Android API level 5 or higher.
- Works with devices that does not
  support C2DM/GCM like the kindle fire.

**cons:**

- Runs a service in the background.
- Its only supported by Xtify 1.x APIs.

Xtify C2DM/GCM:

**pros**

- Works with Android API Level 8 or higher.
- Supported in the new 2.x Xtify APIs.
- It does not run its own service.

**cons**

- it works only with devices that have Google play/Android market.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xtify with GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) if you are using api level 5 or higher. Basically, Xtify will use Google's push server to send the push notifications. If you are supporting below api level 5, then you will need to use XMPP, since devices with sdks lower than 2.0 aren't supported by GCM.

Comment: Which one would be better? if i want to support all the api's ?

Comment: if you want to support all the api's you have to use XMPP. I've used it before. It's perfectly fine if you need to support everyone.