# Android Receive Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, xmpp

I am making a chatting application in which I have successfully implemented chatting functionality. But my chatting works well when the two persons have both opened the chat screen opened in their phones. If the other person is not on the same screen then the chat message sent by one person is lost. I want here that if the other is not on the same screen then the he/she should receive the chat message as a notification. Please help me regarding the same.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any server for this?

Comment: Yes, I using XMPP with openfire

Comment: Why don't you use GCM service for that? GCM doesn't require that you are using the app or not whenever anything gets in the server the android system wakes the app and display the notification.

Comment: ok Thanks. any preferred link for the same??

Comment: But i am bound to use XMPP with openfire.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#server
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242743/gcm-with-php-google-cloud-messaging

Hope that helps!

Comment: See this question here! I think this will solve your confusion.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215113/what-is-diffrence-implementing-xtify-using-gcm-and-xtify-using-xmpp-in-android

Answer (score -1):

You can do like whenever you will send chat msg just check for the user's online status by the server, If it is not then send that msg using notification...

Regards,

Comment: the user will always be online  bro. The thing when he/she is working on the application but is not on the chat screen, then what happens??